# Interpretation of regression coefficients with lagged variables included

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, interpretation, regression-coefficients, lags

I want to model the impact of a firm's degree of operational diversification ($D$) on its firm value ($Q$). To do so, I use the following regression equation:

$$Q_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_2D+\gamma X'+u_{it}  \tag 1$$

The subscripts indicate the time ($t$) and the firm ($i$). $X'$ is a vector of control variables. When estimating this model with firm and industry fixed effects, I receive an estimate of $\beta_2$ which is $0.1336$. What I am interested in is the diversification premium of an average firm. To derive the average diversification premium I multiply $\beta_2$ with the mean of $D$ (${\rm Premium} = \beta_2\bar{D}$).

In a second model, I include a lagged value of firm value:

$$Q_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1Q_{t-1}+\beta_2D+\gamma X'+u_{it}  \tag 2$$

My question is if I can derive the diversification premium from ($2$) in the same manner as in ($1$) by ${\rm Premium} = \beta_2\bar{D}$? Or do I have to account for the lagged value of firm value?

Comment: I fear this may be off-topic here since this is largely an economics question. There is a beta econ SE site that may be a better fit.